# Trouble correlating a bearer token while trying to performance test an application in Microsoft PowerApps using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, token, bearer-token

I am trying to perform some performance tests on a simple app I have developed in PowerApps using JMeter as a learning exercise. After importing the .Har file of the process I want to test to JMeter, I am presented by many Http requests. During a replay of the script The first few Http requests fail due to the following error;

> HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name

In the request body it contains a Bearer token. I am assuming the issue is that I need to correlate this token. The token is a cookie and also exists within the cookie manager. My problem is I cannot find the value in a response to correlate it. Am I assuming right in that my issue lies with the Bearer token and if so what would be the best course of action to try identify the Bearer token from a response. If not what am I doing wrong and could someone point me in the right direction.

Any additional information can be provided that is relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the error:

> The request has an invalid header name

it seems that your [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) configuration is not correct, to wit there is a typo in the [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) name

Just make sure that you have a [`Authorization` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) with the value of `Bearer <your token here>` like:

[image]